# Excel VBA Macro to define number of files and cells copied

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I currently have a macro that copies a given number of cells from a range and pastes them into a new workbook.
the values in these cells are also files which are copied from the sourcepath to dest path.
I define the number I want by changing the range in the 2 parts (`Range("D2:D16"`) and it works fine.

BUT I have to repeat this task about 30 time a day for different numbers of files and so I want the number it copies to be defined by me -probably by a number on a spreadsheet somewhere - *i.e.* if A1 = 20 then it would run the below macro for 20 files if A2 =35 then it would be 35 etc.

Sure this is simple but I can't work it out so I leave you with the "clean" code that works for the manual process! Help gratefully accepted :)

```
  Dim r As Range
  Dim SourcePath As String, DestPath As String, FName As String

  SourcePath = "C:Unique ISRCs\"
  DestPath = "C:old rope\"

  For Each r In Range("D2:D16", Range("D2:D16").End(xlUp))
    'Searches the file with the file mask from the cell (Change this range depending how many tracks I want to copy, in this instance 15)
    FName = Dir(SourcePath & r)
    'Loop while files found
    Do While FName <> ""
      'Copy the file
      FileCopy SourcePath & FName, DestPath & FName
      'Search the next file
      FName = Dir()
    Loop
  Next

Workbooks("English Metadata Template.xlsm").Worksheets("METADATA TEMPLATE").Range("AJ15:AJ60").Value = _
    Workbooks("ISRC's for Comps.xlsm").Worksheets("English").Range("D2:D16").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you could do `For Each r In Range("D2").resize(range("A1").value)`

Comment: I've updated as ** won't show in a code block as bold.  Hopefully the meaning is still clear - feel free to change if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks SJR - that copied the files but I couldn't get the second part of the range to accept the above adjustment so it moved the right number of files over to the right folder but wouldn;t copy the right cells to the worksheet

Comment: For info if you write @SJR I am notified of a response. What exactly is the problem? Your last line is a bit odd as the two ranges are different sizes - what are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Sorry about that...so the last bit of my code (I think) is where it copies the data from and to - ie it goes from the ISRCs for comps over to the English metadata template.
With your solution this part of my macro no longer works - it happily copies the files from one folder to another but not the same data between the spreadsheets.

Comment: As a final point where I have put the range AJ15:AJ60 this is just because I will never go above this number of cells copied over (ie that gives me 45 rows and some will be #N/A if I only copy 15 cells and files worht of data - I then delete the remainder

Comment: Can you not just replace `Range("D2:D16")` in the same way as above? E.g. `Range("AJ15").resize(range("A1").value).Value = _
    Workbooks("ISRC's for Comps.xlsm").Worksheets("English").Range("D2").resize(range("A1").value).Value`. But you must add workbook and sheet references to the A1 reference.

Comment: That worked perfectly - my apologies I hadn't defined the range correctly in my one - your code worked perfectly!
I do have another problem which is more complicated but will try and work it out myself first before posting :)